# An error in applying Riemann-Hurwitz formula?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I did try to compute the genus of a curve of bidegree $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb P ^1 \times \mathbb P^1$. I did choose the curve $X = \{ x_0^ay_0^b = x_1^ay_1^b\}$. Consider the projection to the $x$ component  $\pi : X \to \mathbb P^1$. This is a degree $b$ map with two ramifications points ($0$ and $\infty$), both of index $b-1$. Thus I get $\chi(X) = 2b - 2(b-1) = 2$ which is obviously false. I know the correct answer is $(a-1)(b-1)$. Where is my mistake ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Curve $X$ is not smooth, for some $a$ and $b$ it is even reducible e.g. $a=2$ and $b=4$.

Comment: @Alex : Thanks a lot !